# Get user’s current location Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, cllocationmanager

I am trying to get the location. I implement everything but nothing works.

This is my class:

```
public class Best2 : CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    public CLLocationManager _locationManager;

    private Int32 _numEvento;

    public Best2()
    {
    }

    protected Best2(NSObjectFlag t) : base(t)
    {
    }

    protected internal Best2(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public Best2(Int32 paramEvento)
    {
        _numEvento = paramEvento;

        _locationManager = new CLLocationManager ();
        _locationManager.PausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false;
        _locationManager.DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccurracyBestForNavigation;

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (9, 0)) {
            _locationManager.AllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true;
        }

        _locationManager.Delegate = this;

        StartLocationUpdates();
    }

    public void StartLocationUpdates ()
    {
        if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) {
            _locationManager.RequestLocation();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                String.Format(
                    "FA&)#2 RequestLocation() Data:D {0}"
                    , DateTime.UtcNow
                )
            );

        }
    }

    public override void Failed (CLLocationManager manager, Foundation.NSError error)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
            String.Format(
                "FA&)#2 Failed() Data:D {0}"
                , DateTime.UtcNow
            )
        );
    }

    public override void UpdatedLocation (CLLocationManager manager, CLLocation newLocation, CLLocation oldLocation)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
            String.Format(
                "FA&)#2 UpdatedLocation() Data:D {0}"
                , DateTime.UtcNow
            )
        );
    }
```

I call this way:

```
        Best2 position = new Best2(1);
```

Based in the apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation), I think it should call the method **Failed** if not works and **UpdatedLocation** if works. But nothing is calling.

I already try to put the class receiving events, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi Bruno Costa, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation about [Request Location](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_authorization_level_for_location_services/requesting_always_authorization) we know that if we want to use location in iOS we must follow the steps below:

1. Add the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key and the `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription` key to your Info.plist file.
2. If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, add the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key to your Info.plist file.

Then before `RequestLocation()` we need to call `RequestAlwaysAuthorization()` or `RequestWhenInUseAuthorization()` to get user's authentication.

At last we can get the location but you misunderstand the event:

> I think it should call the method Failed if not works and
>   UpdatedLocation if works.

If it works the event `LocationsUpdated()` will fire not `UpdatedLocation()`.